# HttpsUrlConnection response returned from servlet contains extra 'b''0''\r\n' characters when read through python library

Tags: java, python, servlets, python-requests, httpsurlconnection

I am using HttpsURLConnection to call a server and return the response returned from the HttpsURLConnection from my servlet. I am copying the response from HttpssURLConnection to HttpServletresponse using streams, copying bytes from the httpconnection response input stream to the response's output stream, checking the end by seeing if read returns < 0.

Following is the code for copying the response. The variable `response` is of type `HttpServletResponse` and the variable `httpCon` is of type `HttpsURLConnection`.

```
InputStream responseStream = httpCon.getInputStream();    
if (responseStream != null)
{
  OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len;
  while ((len = responseStream.read(buffer)) >= 0)
  {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
  }
  os.flush();
  os.close();
}
```

On the client side, I am using python requests library to read the response.

What I am seeing that if I use the curl to test my servlet, I am getting the proper response json,  `response = u'{"key":"value"}'`.

If i read it from the requests python, it is putting some extra characters in the response , the response looks like the following
`response = u'b0\r\n{"key":"value"}\r\n0\r\n\r\n'`

Both the strings are unicode. But the second one has extra characters.

Same resonse if I try from curl/Postman restclient, I am able to get it properly. But from python requests, it is not working. I tried another livetest library in python, with that also, it is not working and the response has same characters. I also tried to change the accept-encoding header but it did not have any effect.

Because of this, I am not able to parse the json. 
I don't want to change the client to parse this kind of string.
Can I change something on the server so that it will work correctly?

Comment: Show us the copy code?

Comment: Updated with code for copying the response

Comment: yep the copy code is fine. What's with the u in front of the response? Are you sure you're reading as unicode in Python? A mismatch encoding seems likely...

Comment: u is the unicode. I am just using the requests library in python.

Comment: you can probably ignore the u, it is not part of the string, whereas in the other case the characters b0\r\n are part of the string.

Comment: just verified that python is reading both as unicode., so it does not look like an encoding issue.

Comment: I tried sending different accept-encoding header as well, that also did not had any impact, it was the same response in that case also.

Answer (score 3):

Did the response contain the below header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"?

The response should be in Chunked transfer encoding
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding.

In this case, you get \r\n0\r\n\r\n at the end of the response is as expected since it is terminating symbol of this encoding. I guest curl/Postman just help us to handle Chunked transfer encoding, so you can't find these chunked symbols.